# Create timed label if input does not exist

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I have an entry label where you type a name into. I want it to search through column 0 of the csv file. If that name exists, then it shall be displayed in a listbox that has already been created (this works fine) but if the name does not exist, I want to create a timed label ( the elif section). However, the code I have written displays the label when the name does AND doesn't exist.

```
with open('CLASSES.csv', 'rt')as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    people=[]
    for column in reader:
        if column[0]==entry:
            people.append(column[0:8])

            namebox.delete(0,END)

            nameslist=[x[0] for x in people]
            for names in (nameslist):
                namebox.insert(END, names)

        elif column[0]!=entry:
                INC=Label(master,text='User Does Not Exist',bg='#800000',fg='white')
                INC.grid(row=2,column=3,columnspan=5,sticky='s')
                def af():
                    INC.configure(fg='#800000')             
                INC.after(1000, af)
```

The `if column[0] == entry:` section works fine but I thought I would include it to make it easier to understand how the program works.

Any help would be great!

Comment: There is more than one record in "reader", so some records equal entry and some records do not, so both the if and elif are executed on different records.  Note that and if and else work better here, else covers everything that is not == entry.

Comment: I changed it to else however I still have the same issue as its still searching through the same list and therefore getting results that match and don't but thanks anyway - @CurlyJoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying the record for each entry.

Use a `boolean` typed variable to store if the entry was found. Initialize it with `false` before the loop begins. If an entry is equal, set it to `true`. After the loop check for this value and apply your if branch to it.

**Pseudo code**

```
search = "SomeEntryValue"
found = False
for line in open("csv-file", "r"):
    if line[0] == search:
        found = True
        # Optional Tasks to be done here for each entry
if found:
    # Display the Data
else:
    # display the "User does not exist" message
```

Comment: I tweaked my coding using what you suggested, it now works, thanks!! :)